# How to make a div fill its container with 100% width and height?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am creating a text editor, and I am working on the sizing of my `div`. Unfortunately, it does not take up the whole page. Its `width` and `height` are set to `100%`. Here is the CSS:

```
html, body {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
}
```

If you would like to view the page, you can see it [here](http://zoozaedit.x10.mx/embed). Thank you all so much for your help.

Comment: Do not use the `style` attribute on the initial page load.

Comment: I would recommend you create a jsfiddle or at least a complete snipped with the div's markup and css. Also, im almost sure this has been answered before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it's not taking up the entire height is because the parent objects are most likely not 100% as you would like. Place the following code before the container style:

```
 html,body{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to include `margin: none;` and `padding: none;` in your initial declarations for `html` and `body`:

```
html, body {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    margin: none;
    padding: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give a height to `editBox` as well which is equal to the difference from the height of above element. Set the margin, padding to 0 for the html and body elements for avoiding overflow.

```
#editBox {
  height: calc(100% - 30px);
}

html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Hmm. there is a bit of overflow when I embed it...

Answer (score 0):

I've changed it up a little bit

```
html,
body,
.container {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}

.header {
  height: 30px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 0px;
}

#editBox {
  height: calc(100% - 33px);
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  overflow: scroll;
}

img.icon {
  width: 15px;
}
```

Here it is

http://jsfiddle.net/link2twenty/y9esbeLc/